# Function of $clog2(N) in Mojo IDE

Tags: system-verilog

I am a beginner in this, but I was wondering what exactly is the function of $clog2(N) in general? Some websites say that it is the number of address bits needed for a memory of size N and not the number of bits needed to express the value N. What does that mean?

Comment: I think your 2nd sentence is not clear.  A value like `$clog2(2**N)` is N, but needs to be N+1 for the value.  Example `$clog2('d8)` is the same as `$clog2('d7)`.  But to represent the number 8 requires four bits and only three for 7.  I believe this is the aspect the 'website' is getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 20.8.1 *Integer math functions*

> The system function `$clog2` shall return the ceiling of the log base 2 of the argument (the log rounded up to an integer value). The argument can be an integer or an arbitrary sized vector value. The argument shall be treated as an unsigned value, and an argument value of 0 shall produce a result of 0.
>
> This system function can be used to compute the minimum address width necessary to address a memory of a given size or the minimum vector width necessary to represent a given number of states.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> integer result;
> result = $clog2(n);
> ```